# Transforming IF statements to FOR or WHILE (Shell Script)

Tags: shell, scripting

The following code is displaying a *Progress Bar* on an HTML page. It runs fine but takes up far to many lines of code.

**QUESTION:**
- How would I go about transforming this into a `for` or `while` loop, replicating its functionality?

```
if [ $per_usage -ge 1 ] && [ $per_usage -le 10 ]
    then
        indg="|"
        indb=""
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 10 ] && [ $per_usage -le 20 ]
    then
        indg="||"
        indb=""
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 20 ] && [ $per_usage -le 30 ]
    then
        indg="|||"
        indb=""
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 30 ] && [ $per_usage -le 40 ]
    then
        indg="||||"
        indb=""
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 40 ] && [ $per_usage -le 50 ]
    then
        indg="|||||"
        indb=""
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 50 ] && [ $per_usage -le 60 ]
    then
        indg="|||||"
        indb="|"
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 60 ] && [ $per_usage -le 70 ]
    then
        indg="|||||"
        indb="||"
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 70 ] && [ $per_usage -le 80 ]
    then
        indg="|||||"
        indb="|||"
        indr=""
elif [ $per_usage -gt 80 ] && [ $per_usage -le 90 ]
    then
        indg="|||||"
        indb="||"
        indr="||"
elif [ $per_usage -gt 90 ]
    then
        indg=""
        indb=""
        indr="||||||||||"
else
        indg=""
        indb=""
        indr=""
fi
```

For example my output is like if per_usage value is `41`

`41 % |||||`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing can be looped pretty easily:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_string () {
    per_usage="$1"
    if [ "$per_usage" -le 100 ] && [ "$per_usage" -ge 0 ]; then
        echo -en "${per_usage}%\t"
        bars=$(($per_usage / 10 + 1))
        printf "%0.s|" $(seq 1 $bars)
        echo
    fi
}

i=0
while [ "$i" -le 100 ]; do
    string=$(get_string "$i")
    echo "$string"
    let i++
done
```

In this example, the `get_string` function can be used to generate a string based on an input number. For instance, `get_string 41` will print `41% |||||`. In the little `while` loop below, the string for 0 - 100 is stored in the `$string` variable and printed.

`bars` stores the number of bars to print. Just one bar per 10%. Then `printf` and `seq` are used to print a `|` `bars` number of times.

Hopefully with this, you'll be on the right track to cleaning up your code.

Comment: Thanks John for taking out time to reply. Works like a charm. I was able to fit this in my program with only below code get_string () {
    per_usage="$1"
    if [ "$per_usage" -le 100 ] && [ "$per_usage" -ge 0 ]; then
        echo -en "${per_usage}%\t"
        bars=$(($per_usage / 10))
        printf "%0.s|" $(seq 1 $bars)
        echo
    fi
}